# How to find folder only containing exact text

Tags: linux, command-line, centos6

I am using CentOS 6.8 and I am attempting to set a variable (let's call it fPath) to be the file path of a file (let's call the folder Foo).  The main point is that I will not know where exactly the user has installed the folder Foo.

The problem is that my find commands will return all folders containing the string Foo (like inside the Foo folder, there's a Foo_logs, Foo_apps, FooMore, ect.).  I want my find command to find/return ONLY the Foo folder path.

I have tried searching and the closest attempt I've made is using the command:

```
find -regex ./Foo
```

However this will only return the Foo folder path if I'm already inside the directory containing the Foo folder.  I want to be in any directory and apply the find command to return just the Foo folder path.

Other commands I've attempted are :

```
locate Foo

find -type d -name Foo

find ./Foo

locate /Foo

locate ./Foo

find Foo | -wholename '*/Foo/*'

find ./Foo | -wholename '*/Foo/*'

find .*/Foo | -wholename '*/Foo/*'
```

Edit : formatting

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, `find` will do the job perfectly:

`find / -type d -name Foo`

- `/` is where it'll start searching from.
- `-type d` means directories only
- `-name Foo` means files named exactly `Foo`.

Don't use `-wholename` here because it will expect the whole path to match, not juste one of the (sub)directories.

Comment: Thank you, but this still returns ALL directories containing the string Foo (like Foo_logs).  I am trying to get a single return for the file Foo, the file name equals Foo and nothing else (no '_' or 'log', etc.).

Comment: If there are multiple directories named Foo, you'll get them in the output. There's no way your shell will "guess" which one is the one you're looking for unless you give it more conditions. As for Foo_log, it won't show up in the result unless it's under a "Foo" directory (which is what you seem to be looking for in the first place).

Comment: Oh; I see.  For clarification, there should only one directory/folder named (only) Foo; however is there a way to say in the find command to ignore anything else in the directory that CONTAINS the string "Foo".  Like I previously said, I don't want Foo_logs directory which is inside Foo; I just want the Foo filepath only in the output.  Is that possible?

So basically I have something like this:


                Foo

               /     \

   Foo_logs    FooMore

What I want find to return is JUST the Foo parent's filepath.  The others have more than just "Foo" in there filenames.